# How to deal with punctuation in an ElasticSearch field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field in a document stored in Elastic Search, which I want to be analyzed as a full text field.  In one case, it contains a value for the `name` field like this:

```
A&B Corp
```

I want to be able to search the documents for an auto-complete widget, using a query like this (suppose the user typed `A&B` into the autocomplete field).  The intention is to match documents that contain the any terms with the typed prefix.

```
{   "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "A&B*",
          "fields": [
            "firstName",
            "lastName",
            "name",
            "key",
            "email"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "environmentId": [
            "foo"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```

My mapping for the name field looks like this:

```
"name": {
    "type": "string"
},
```

But, I get no results.  The query structure works for documents that don't have `&` in the field, so I'm pretty sure that is part of the problem.

But, I'm not sure how to deal with this.  I am pretty sure I still want to analyze the field for full text search.

In addition, if I add a space before the `*` in the query (ie, `"query": "A&B *",`) then I get results including `A&B`, so I don't *think* it is just discarding the ampersand and treating the `A` and `B` as separate terms.

Should I change my mapping? The query?

Comment: You can check what tokens the standard analyzer produces for the input `A&B Corp` using `curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_analyze?analyzer=standard&text=A%26B Corp"` - you get three tokens, `a`, `b`, `corp`. Would you expect it to produce two tokens, `a&b` and `corp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Query_string query has a set of reserved characters that needs to be escaped.

[query_string : Read the reserved characters section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)

So to search for

> 'A&B'  (or)  'A&B Corp' (or) 'A&B....'
>
> Your query must be "A&B\\*" such that the query_string parser treats
>   it as a * wildcard operator.

1. While currently your query is searching for exact match of
   **"A&B*"** it expects asterik to be part of your data.
2. And when you search **"A&B *"** the whitespace is a reserved
   character so its
       now searching for "A&B" (or) "*" and hence you get a match in this
       case.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have done the trick! I was focusing on the `&` this whole time, and I didn't think to question the rest of the query.